# How to store NSMutableArray of UILabel in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

in my app user can add label and rotate and move position of label. and add label is programmeticaly click on add label programmeticaly label add in view. now i want to implement undo and redo fetures. so i store label in `NSArray`. i think if i store in label in array and then array store in `NSUserDefaults` with key and when user click on Undo so i remove all label from view and add label from array which i store but lable in `NSMutableArray` but it not store in `NSUserDefaults`.

```
NSData *lbldata = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:labels];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:lbldata forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"customLabel%i",UndoKey]];
```

i try simpla array like

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:labels forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"customLabel%i",UndoKey]];
```

but it give me error.

in above code labels is `NSMutableArray`. Any suggestion are welcome. thanks for your time Have a great Day.

Comment: Dont store the label, store your custom logic representation of the label, e.g. only the x/y coordinates, maybe the text, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your goal here is to allow users to have undo/redo you say.  There's an entire system for that called `NSUndoManager`. You should read up on its documentation instead of trying to jury rig `NSUserDefaults` for something it wasn't intended:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/UndoManager.html

Further, `NSUserDefaults` is not a great place for storing full UI object types.  Instead, if say you wanted to store some criteria about a UI element to re-display it the same way next time you open the app, then you could just store the criteria you need to save. For instance, perhaps you store the `NSString` associated with the `text` property of a `UILabel` and you store a `CGPoint` associated with its location and an `NSNumber` associated with its rotation angle, etc.

But for undo/redo please do not use `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the important properties of UILabel such as NSDictionary

-frame, string, color etc.

and then use one of the following option to store/delete/update labels:

1. Use sqlite to store properties.
2. Use CoreData to store properties.
3. Write properties to .plist file
4. Store NSDictionary to NSUserDefaults